# Make gradle compileJava dependsOn spotlessApply

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle project with several submodules. In my project there is a spotless task configured. Now I want to make a `compileJava` task dependent on `spotlessApply` task. I try it in this way:

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.gradle.spotless'

    spotless {
        java {
            target 'src/**/*.java'
            licenseHeaderFile  "$rootDir/buildSrc/CopyrightHeader.java"
            importOrder(['java', 'javax', 'org', 'com'])
            eclipseFormatFile "$rootDir/buildSrc/formatter.xml"
        }
        format 'misc', {
            target 'src/**/*.md', 'src/**/*.xml', 'src/**/*.xsd', 'src/**/*.xsl'
            indentWithSpaces()
            trimTrailingWhitespace()
            endWithNewline()
        }
    }

    compileJava.dependsOn spotlessApply
}
```

But it produces an error:

> Could not get unknown property 'spotlessApply' for project (...) of
> type org.gradle.api.Project.

I also tried something like this:

```
compileJava.dependsOn project.tasks.findByName('spotlessApply')
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Spotless plugin creates its tasks in an `project.afterEvaluate` block to allow you to configure the extension before it creates the task(s) - see [here](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/blob/245b35cbfe810728039341ae950a7fc31f74d2c8/plugin-gradle/src/main/java/com/diffplug/gradle/spotless/SpotlessPlugin.java#L50)

To solve this, simply depend on the task's name (i.e. as a string) instead and Gradle will resolve the task when its needed.

```
compileJava.dependsOn 'spotlessApply'
```

Comment: Such a simple line to make life easier! We don't use spotless to have something to tell me what I did wrong, but to have an uniform format among all developers and increase readability. To find out at build time that you didn't satisfy the rules (that could be fixed automatically), is just annoying (and makes it hard to convince the team).